# Any change in settings causes the command plate to come up with "null password (Press 'Enter' to confirm or 'Escape' to cancel)"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I change any of the settings in VSCode, the command plate to come up with "null password (Press 'Enter' to confirm or 'Escape' to cancel)". Hitting enter is enough to make things work fine, however, it is still annoying. I am not sure of the reason behind this and was wondering if anybody came across something similar.

Attached is a picture of the command plate (just in case...).[image]

Comment: This is caused by one of your extensions. Please try disabling them individually to track down which one is prompting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. It looks like the culprit is [SQLTools](https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools).

Here's the line of code that produces the dialog:
https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/blob/0865cf0/src/sqltools.ts#L419-L424
This was super hard to track down, since it took me a while to figure out that the "Press 'Enter' to confirm" part is built-in to all VSCode prompt dialogs, and that string is not provided by the extension.

Putting this in my `settings.json` made the extension stop prompting me:

```json
"sqltools.autoConnectTo": "blah",
```

(The default value is `null`. Putting a string somehow causes it to generate an error in the console but whatever, it solves the problem.)

I hope this works for you! You can also:

- Disable or uninstall the extension if you don't need it at all
- File an issue to let the author know: https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues

Comment: Dude, you're awesome... Thanks for saving me tons of time!

Comment: I filed an issue and quoted your insights: https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/76.

Comment: Hi, I'm Matheus, the author of SQLTools.

Yeah, certainly it's because of the extension.

I'm fixing it right now.

Thanks [@interestinglythere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782045/interestinglythere) for tracking down the bug :D

Answer (score 2):

Like [interestinglythere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782045/interestinglythere) said, this is likely caused by the [SQLTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools) extension.

To fix, do this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to open `settings.json`
2. Add line `"sqltools.autoConnectTo": "Prevent Dialog Box",`
   [image: SQLTools prevent dialog box]
3. Save and open the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) to reload with the command :

   ```
   >Reload Window
   ```

Done!

Comment: Note any string will do as long as `"sqltools.autoConnectTo"` is set to something else than `null`.